# bootstrap tagsinput - How can i show tags only in input element (restrict max tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-tags-input

I would like tags to be filled as wide as the input element.

1. If the tags are filled beyond the width of the input element, I want to hide  from being added to the bottom as shown.

[image]

2. I want to be able to see hidden tags by clicking on an input element or other element (like sliding toggle).
3. Or, let me tell you a jquery tag with this feature, instead of bootstrap.

cshtml.

```
 <span class="search_op_bar"><input type="text" id="trans_Langs_tag" data-role="tagsinput"></span>
```

custom css

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
padding: 4px 6px;
/*color: #555;*/
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 4px;
max-width: 100%;
height:30px; /*Custom*/
line-height: 23px;/*Custom*/
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 0 6px;
margin: 0;
width: auto;
display:none;/*Custom*/
max-width: inherit;
height:30px; /*Custom*/
}
```

Comment: TagsInput has an option for [`maxTags`](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#options), is that actually what you want? or do you want unlimited tags, just the excess are hidden?

Comment: Tags are still added, but if they go beyond the size of the input element, I want to hide the stuff that is added after that.

Comment: but still allow more tags to be added?

Comment: yeah, That's right.